# Header config when exporting logs using sinks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

What is the header structure or can the header be customized when exporting logs using sinks to Cloud Pub/Sub topics?

When receiving the logs I want to reference metadata in the header. I want to know which GCP service that the log came from.

The header from the sent message to the receiver of the subscribed URL. When you configure a Pub/Sub topic in GCP and add a subscription to a URL. The header of the message sent to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I created a topic and a subscription.  I then wrote a client that retrieved messages from the subscription and logged them.  The payload for a sink wired to Pub/Sub contained:

```
{
  insertId:
  logName:
  receiveTimestamp:
  resource: {
     project_id:
     type:
  }
  textPayload:
  timestamp:
}
```

Comment: My payload is different, but either way, I'm asking about the header of the request that sends the payload. I don't want to have to reference the payload, only the header.

Comment: What kind of information are we hoping to find in the header?  Do you have an example data field or piece of information that you are looking to acquire?

Comment: I want to know which GCP service that the log came from.

Comment: I checked the StackDriver docs.  If we look in the payload of the published message that was published by StackDriver, the message contains a `resource` object and that object describes who/what issued the log message originally.  To see the set of available sources run `gcloud logging resource-descriptors list`.

Comment: Anything in the header identifying the service?

Comment: When we look at a Pub/Sub message that is received, we see that the message contains a body.  From what I can see, the body that is received from StackDriver looks like the message structure in the posted answer.  I.e. it is a JSON string.  In that JSON string there is an object called `resource` and that object describes the source of the original StackDriver logger.  From what I can see, there don't appear to be any *headers* in the story.

Comment: Okay, guess I'm looking for the header from the sent message to the receiver of the subscribed URL. When you configure a Pub/Sub topic in GCP and add a subscription to a URL. The header of the message sent to the URL.